# How to retrieve global var values from a script using selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium

Need help in retrieving values from script using python selenium. Few values are predefined and rest keeps on updating. Hope someone could help in retrieving the both. Tried few methods which gave no intended result.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import unittest
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
url = "https://demo.applitools.com/hackathonV2.html"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test2(self):
      element = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
      element.send_keys("xxxx")
      element1 = driver.find_element_by_id("password") 
      element1.send_keys("k")
      element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

      element= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="showExpensesChart"]')
      element.click()

      element= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="addDataset"]')
      element.click()

      #need to get the global var values(months, barchartdata)
      c=driver.execute_script('return global')



if  __name__=="__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Data to be retrieved :  BarChartData,Data Updated values when "Show data for next year" is clicked.

[image]

Comment: it is variable in `JavaScript` so use `JavaScript` to get it.

Comment: yea. I tried by altering the attributes for" driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('a')") ". But nothing seems to work. and in the script the function name is not defined as you can see in the image. So how what to use instead of  " return document.getElementsByTagName('a') "?

Comment: For values which doesn't change you can get HTML as text and cut off from this text. If it has JSON format then you can use python's module `json` to convert to python's structure.

Comment: Why do you try to get tag `<a>` if value is in JavaScript. To get tag you can use `driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')` and later you can get text or attributes from this tag.

Comment: "document.getElementsByTagName('a')  " this was just a try to understand how it works. Thant's all. So you are recommending to use scraping for this? or we can can do it just by using selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the below solution to get variable value from

```
labels = driver.execute_script('return barChartData.labels')
print labels



data = driver.execute_script('return barChartData.datasets[0].data')
print data
```

**OutPut**

```
[u'January', u'February', u'March', u'April', u'May', u'June', u'July']
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
```

Comment: would you kind enough to accept my answer and hit up vote button once you verify answer from your end

Comment: I found out the same solution. Thank you for the great help. Btw could you please tell how to get the values for "barChartData.datasets[0].data" replacing 0 with i in the range (0,any number). I have tried but in JS i get only the last element.

Comment: upvoted. could you please help me with the above issue.
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    
       return (window.barChartData.datasets[i].label)
     
    } 
gives only last value for i=2. How to get the other values?